# ¿Estaría bíen sobreescribir el método de la interfaz en el subtipo del tipo declarado?

Tags: java

Vale y si implemento una interfaz una vez establecido el contrato, no lo sobrescribo en esa clase donde he hecho `public class nombre implements interface` sino en su subtipo previamente creado del tipo declarado que es **nombre**, y su subtipo sería por ejemplo **subnombre**.

Comment: Nombre deberá ser Abstract para que el metodo pueda estar vacío...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay ningún problema en ello y es correcto, en la clase Nombre los métodos del contrato con la interface quedarán expresados pero sin codificacion y, en la subclase Subnombre, los puedes sobreescribir con la implementación necesaria.
Por otro lado, si no deseas que la clase Nombre tenga que implementarlos, puedes hacerla abstract y esto obligará a sus subclases a implementar los métodos del contrato con todas interfaces implementadas. Normalmente esto se usa cuando asi cuando la clase Nombre no tiene la información necesaria para codificar esos métodos y si la tendrán sus subclases.

Comment: La clase abstracta porque tiene métodos concretos y métodos abstractos? Que función tienen, esto que he mencionado sería un buen ejemplo sin más o hay algún argumento más supremo?

Comment: La clase abstracta tiene algunos métodos abstractos y otos no porque define un nuevo tipo pero a nivel tan general que tiene cosas que puede implementar y cosas que aun no. Eesas cosas que no puede implementar se traducen en metodos abstractos que quedan ya expresados para que sus subclases (que contarán con mayor nivel de detalle) puedan codificarlos con sus particularidades. En tu ejemplo el argumento de que esto es correcto es que estas modelando tu diseño de clases acorde al paradigma de objetos.